# What are some examples of applied machine learning problems that requires using mixed models?

Tags: machine-learning, mixed-model, nonparametric, intuition

What are some examples of applied machine learning problems that requires using mixed models? I'm just introduced to the notion of mixed models.  As I understand it, it is a combination of parametric model such as logistic function and non-parametric model attempting to model random effects that can be intractable with parametric models.  What are some real-world examples that might be useful to develop some intuition or big-picture understanding of this method?